# Tensorflow Object Detection NewRandomAccessFile failed to create/open

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run the object detection API on a set of rat images, and it's not detecting my `.pbtxt` file. I'm running Windows 10, TensorFlow 1.13, Python 3.6.8.

Here is what I am running from the object detection directory:

`(mv) D:\training\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection>python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config`

And I am getting to following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: D:\training\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\training\rat_face_detection.pbtxt : The system cannot find the file specified.; No such file or directory
```

This is my `\training` directory:

```
05/22/2019  02:15 PM    <DIR>          .
05/22/2019  02:15 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/22/2019  02:38 PM             4,995 pipeline.config
05/22/2019  02:15 PM                42 rat_face_detection.pbtxt.txt
05/22/2019  02:37 PM             4,995 ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
           3 File(s)         10,032 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  994,458,820,608 bytes free
```

So the file is indeed in the correct spot.

Here is the value of `label_map_path`: `"D:\\training\\Tensorflow\\models\\research\\object_detection\\training\\rat_face_detection.pbtxt"`

I've tried forward slashes but saw on another thread that backslashes are required for windows.

I know that `models\research\` and `\models\research\slim` are on the path.  I've also built in both `\research` and `\research\slim` using `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install` in both.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tensorflow object detection API does not officially support Windows, if you have access to a Linux platform, it would be much easier.

Comment: The label map file should be named `rat_face_detection.pbtxt`, just remove `.txt` in the end.